# Post to my wall with picture from my albums

Tags: android, ios, facebook

When I upload the post to my wall, I'd like to see not only a message, but also a picture.
If I put (along with the other parameters) a string with URL of the image for "picture" parameter, it works, but **only** in case if the image is in some side-part server, not in my Facebook albums.

And when I try to use the url of image from my album, I just get "Auth exception" with no explanation in response (it's just 'nil'); I use the last Hackbook example and on base of it make the request like this:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Some message", @"message",
                               @"http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/62347_158935964133931_100000525850093_395542_6306928_n.jpg", @"link",
                               @"http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/62347_158935964133931_100000525850093_395542_6306928_n.jpg", @"picture",
                               nil];
    [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                            andParams:params
                            andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                            andDelegate:self];
```

The references can be opened in a separate browser (not containing any cookies), but with them I get crash.
If to change the references to smth. like

> https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png

Everything works fine.

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since I've lost a whole lot of time to find out what's going on, I want to share what I've found, since I wouldn't like anybody to have such a stupid time with facebook api as I do.

I found, that in fact there was a description of exception (I didn't look at the right place), and the text of it is:

> Error! Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x4e3b8f0 {error={type = mutable dict, count = 3,
>   entries =>
>       2 : {contents = "type"} = {contents = "OAuthException"}
>       3 : {contents = "message"} = {contents = "(#100) **FBCDN image is not allowed in stream**: http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/431663_370671769627015_100000525850093_1341387_699903787_n.jpg"}
>       6 : {contents = "code"} = 100
>   }
>   }

Using the bolded part of the exception above, you can find a lot developers' complains about this problem.

And here's an excerpt from *developers.facebook.com*:

> We no longer allow stream stories to contain images that are hosted on the fbcdn.net domain. The images associated with these URLs aren't always optimized for stream stories and occasionally resulted in errors, leading to a poor user experience. Make sure your stream attachments don't reference images with this domain. You should host the images locally

So, guys, if you have an extremely need of showing a picture in your post - start to prepare a third-party server to store there images for you. Let me know, if I'm wrong with that - you'll make me happier :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I came to the conclusion that the problem is the image size you are trying to link, for me works only if it's a small image.

However, how about linking the facebook page that contains the photo?

```
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=MY_PHOTO_ID
```